# How to process JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, data-structures

I have a .JSON file that has content as:

```
"Name":"something"
"A":10
"B": 12

"Name":"something else"
 "A":5
 "B":9
  ....
```

I want to read this file and then find among these objects which one have the most number of parts(sum of A+B). What would be a good approach to that? I thought about reading JSON data in a Map, and then going through each object of the Map, finding the its total number of A+B, and then storing that in another linked list as `LinkedList<String,Integer>` (where String would be a name, and Integer would be the sum of A+B). Then after that sort LinkedList, and then findout which ever has the most number of A+B. Would this be a good solution?

Comment: Why not just keep track of the largest seen so far? Why put them all in a list? If you're going to put them in a list and sort it, make it an ArrayList which will be more efficient for sorting, not a LinkedList.

Comment: I didn't see `LinkedList<String, Integer>` before because the angle brackets in your question were hidden (treated as an invalid HTML tag), but that is not a valid type. A `List` only takes a single generic type parameter. It isn't like a `Map.`

Comment: @DavidConrad Actually I want to somehow sort it, not just max value. I guess I should put it in a arraylist. thanks,

Comment: Create a class to hold the names and sums, make it comparable by the sum, put them in a list, and sort it.